# Java: Is it possible to exclude taking something from a super class

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm working on an assignment dealing with class inheritance and have everything done and working properly except for a string format method. The output of the program should look like this:

```
Base Salary Plus Commissioned Employee: Sue Smith with ssn: 222-22-2222
Gross Sales: $3000.00 
Commission Rate: 0.05 
with Base Salary:$300.00 
Earnings: $450.00
```

but it is printing like this:

```
Base Salary Plus Commissioned Employee: Sue Smith with ssn: 222-22-2222
Gross Sales: $3000.00 
Commission Rate: 0.05 
Earnings: $450.00
with Base Salary:$300.00 
Earnings: $450.00
```

The problem is that in the output, "Earnings: $450.00" is printing before "with Base Salary: $300.00". The class **BasePlusCommissionEmployee** extends from class **CommissionEmployee**. Each class has it's own **toString** method, and the BasePlusCommissionEmployee does call the super.toString(), which I believe this is causing the issue.

I need to be able to have the class inherit from the CommissionEmployee but not bring the "Earnings" until the end (as shown).

This is the code for the toString in the CommissionEmployee class:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {                                    
        return String.format("%s: %s%n%s: $%.2f \n%s: %.2f \n%s $%.2f",    
         "Commissioned Employee", super.toString(),              
         "Gross Sales", getGrossSales(),                       
         "Commission Rate", getCommissionRate(), 
         "Earnings:", earnings());             
   }
```

This is the code for the toString in BasePlusCommissionEmployee class (which extends from CommissionEmployee):

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {                                            
        return String.format("\n%s %s \n%s:$%,.2f \n%s $%.2f",                       
            "Base Salary Plus", super.toString(),                            
            "with Base Salary", getBaseSalary(),
            "Earnings:",earnings());                             
   }
```

This is the test code running in the main:

```
CommissionEmployee employee1 = new CommissionEmployee("Fred", "Jones", "111-11-1111", 2000.0, .05);
BasePlusCommissionEmployee employee2 = new BasePlusCommissionEmployee("Sue", "Smith", "222-22-2222", 3000.0, .05, 300);
System.out.printf("%s%s%s%s%s", employee1, employee2, employee3, employee4, employee5);
```

All help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost this exact problem is solved in the first chapter of the book [Refactoring](https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html) by Martin Fowler, section "Decomposing and Redistributing the Statement Method". The `toString()` method can be decomposed as follows in the base class:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getReportHeader() 
                + getReportBase() 
                + getReportSpecifics() 
                + getReportFooter();
    }

    protected String getReportHeader() {
        return String.format("%s: %s",
                             "Commissioned Employee", super.toString());
    }

    protected String getReportBase() {
        return String.format("\n%s %s \n%s:$%,.2f",
                             "Gross Sales", getGrossSales(),
                             "Commission Rate", getCommissionRate());
    }

    protected String getReportSpecifics() {
        return "";
    }

    protected String getReportFooter() {
        return String.format("\n%s $%.2f", "Earnings:", earnings());
    }
```

and then the required parts can be overridden in the child class:

```
    @Override
    protected String getReportSpecifics() {
        return String.format("\n%s %s \n%s:$%,.2f",
                             "Base Salary Plus", getBaseSalaryPlus(),
                             "with Base Salary", getBaseSalary());
    }
```

I suggest reading the whole book, though. It's worth its price many times over.

Comment: I believe this puts the "Base Salary Plus" output in the wrong place in the derived class. I'd suggest overriding `getReportHeader()` in the derived class to fix this ...

Answer (score 0):

We are going to store all the key-value pairs that needs to be printed in a Map. For this purpose, we would be using a tweaked LinkedHashMap (to prevent insertion order in the case of duplicates - such as `Earnings:`'s also).

```
class TweakedHashMap<K,V> extends LinkedHashMap<K,V> {

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        super.remove(key);
        return super.put(key, value);
    }

}
```

Now, use to following methods in

```
class CommissionEmployee{

    ...
    ...

    public Map<Object,Object> getToStringMap(){
        Map<Object,Object> map = new TweakedHashMap<>();
        map.put("Commissioned Employee",super.toString());
        map.put("Gross Sales",getGrossSales());
        map.put("Commission Rate",getCommissionRate());
        map.put("Earnings:",earnings());
        returun map;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getToStringMap().entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey()+ " : " + e.getValue()).collect(
            Collectors.joining(",\n"));
    }
}


class BasePlusCommissionEmployee extends CommissionEmployee{

    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public Map<Object,Object> getToStringMap(){
        Map<Object,Object> superMap = super.getToStringMap();
        map.put("Base Salary Plus Commissioned Employee",superMap.get("Commissioned Employee"));
        map.put("with Base Salary",getBaseSalary());
        map.put("Earnings:",earnings());
        returun map;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getToStringMap().entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey()+ " : " + e.getValue()).collect(
            Collectors.joining(",\n"));
    }
}
```

Following will be the output:

```
Base Salary Plus Commissioned Employee: Sue Smith with ssn: 222-22-2222,
Gross Sales: $3000.00,
Commission Rate: 0.05,
with Base Salary:$300.00,
Earnings: $450.00
```

Comment: does not solve the OP's problem because you are changing the behavior of the OP's base class

Comment: I've tried this, but the problem then is that the "Earnings" does not print for the CommissionEmployee output as I need it to. Thank you though!

Comment: Not only does this answer not solve the code duplication problem, but it is overly complicated too

Comment: @AngeloKwak updated the answer. It's a bit of an overwork but it should work fine.

Comment: @MFisherKDX by saying `Not only does this answer not solve the code duplication problem`, do you mean duplicate code in `toString()` method? If yes, we can create a utility method to resolve that. But, indeed, it is a bit complicated.

Comment: No.  I mean this answer is worthless.  **It won't even compile** -- `getToStringMap()` doesn't return anything.  And even if you fix that, it has logical errors that will generate the wrong output.  And furthermore it **doesn't solve the problem!** All you have done is move the duplicated code from `toString()` to `getToStringMap()`.

Comment: I might have missed the return statement but how does it not solve the problem? All you keep saying is it doesn't solve the problem/logical errors. Try and be precise so that it helps others.

Comment: You didn't solve the problem because you still have the code duplication issue the OP is trying to resolve.  Your duplication is two `map.put("Earnings:",earnings())` statements.  Additionally, your code is incorrect as it generates the wrong output.  For instance, your derived class doesn't print the "Gross Sales" or "Commission Rate" fields as your "following will be the output" statement claims. If you correct this, you will have even more code duplication.  Also, you only need 1 `toString()` function, in the base class.  The function is defined the exact same way in the derived class.

Comment: first, `map.put("Earnings:",earnings())` is not code duplication. If your child class has overridden the method, you'll have to add this manually else the base class' method will get called. Secondly, I forgot to inherit the base class. With that done, the output is now correct. Thirdly, I need diff `toString()` methods because the content to be printed is diff in both classes. Fourthly, The function is *NOT* defined the exact same way in the derived class

Comment: You obviously never tried to compile or run your code. It still won't compile because you never defined `map` in your derived class's `getToStringMap()` function. You obviously never ran your code because it would still generate the wrong output -- not as you claim "Following will be the output". And you still don't understand what the OP is after -- see the accepted answer for how to refactor.  I'm done here. Good day.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't compile the code - I'd told you this if you had simply asked. The answer was to guide the OP towards the solution & unlike you, I'm sure, he is smart enough to focus on the main logic instead of focusing on trifles

Answer (score 0):

You need to redefine the toString behaviour in the subclass without calling super.toString()

This will give you the freedom to choose what fields to display and in what order. But the biggest drawback is that it duplicates code which I feel is not worth it (since you also have to take care of printing the data from the parent class of CommissionEmployee).